# Parse database not logging in users

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, parse-dashboard

I am trying to login as a user anonymously but it isn't working.

Here is my code:

```
if (ParseUser.getCurrentUser() == null){
      ParseAnonymousUtils.logIn(new LogInCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
          if (e==null){
            Log.i("login", "yes");
          }
        }
      });
    }
```

I am sure that `ParseUser.getCurrentUser` is null because this is the first time I am logging in to parse.

In the parse dashboard, the user is not seen even if I refresh.

Comment: @Chinez Please answer the question after editing

Comment: Have you tried to add some logs to make sure the logIn function is being executed and also there is no error?

Comment: The problem was a user was already logged in so I couldn't log in a new user without logging out old user